# How Do I Custom 'Order BY' in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql query:

```
SELECT merchantNames.strippedName,merchantNames.lastCached,merchantNames.id
FROM merchantNames 
JOIN autoCoupons  
ON merchantNames.rawName = autoCoupons.merchantName
WHERE NOW() > autoCoupons.startDate AND autoCoupons.startDate > merchantNames.lastCached
OR NOW() > autoCoupons.endDate AND autoCoupons.endDate > merchantNames.lastCached
OR NOW() > autoCoupons.timeAdded AND autoCoupons.timeAdded > merchantNames.lastCached
OR merchantNames.lastCached < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
GROUP BY merchantNames.strippedName
ORDER BY merchantNames.pageviews DESC
```

How do I set this query to order the results in such a way that those that meet the first three lines of the WHERE clause criteria are at the top and those that only meet the bottom line are at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways to get the results you want for *this* query, but for a "custom `ORDER BY`", you can just order by the result of a boolean clause. `DESC` will put true (1) results first and false (0) results second. In your case, it's easiest to read and write this query with a nested `SELECT` (below), but of course you can write a longer query with the explicit conditions in the ORDER BY, which could be significantly faster.

```
SELECT r.strippedName, r.lastCached, r.id
FROM
    (SELECT
        merchantNames.strippedName,
        merchantNames.lastCached,
        merchantNames.id,
        merchantNames.pageviews,
        (NOW() > autoCoupons.startDate AND autoCoupons.startDate > merchantNames.lastCached) AS a,
        (NOW() > autoCoupons.endDate AND autoCoupons.endDate > merchantNames.lastCached) AS b,
        (NOW() > autoCoupons.timeAdded AND autoCoupons.timeAdded > merchantNames.lastCached) AS c,
        (merchantNames.lastCached < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY) AS d
    FROM merchantNames 
    JOIN autoCoupons ON merchantNames.rawName = autoCoupons.merchantName
    GROUP BY merchantNames.strippedName) AS r
WHERE r.a OR r.b OR r.c OR r.d
ORDER BY (r.a OR r.b OR r.c) DESC, pageviews DESC
```

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the AS at the end of those lines will gather up it's boolean result from both sides of the AND and not just from the tail end of it?

Comment: You can put in parentheses to be sure.

Comment: It works, but there are just a few very minor errors in it so, not to be critical, but to help clear it up, I'll explain them. You need to add commas after 'AS a' and 'AS b'. Also, I needed to add 'merchantNames.pageviews,' just below 'merchantNames.id,' in order to be able to use that in the final ORDER BY clause. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Divide the query in two and use UNION to join the results together.